# SwiftUI: Aligning single line text to first line of multiline text

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am having difficulty making the short 1-line text view to be on the same line as the first line of multi-line text view. Here is a picture to demonstrate my problem:

[image]

The only way that I can come up with is to insert an end-line to the short string so that it technically becomes a 2-line string:

```
HStack {
    Text("Short text\n")
    Spacer()
    Text("This is a very long string that will be wrapped to multiple lines")
 }
```

But this only works if the long string is 2 lines, if it is any more than that, it won't work. Can someone let me know if there is a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply change HStack alignment to `firstTextBaseline`, it's `.center` by default.

```swift
HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
    ...
}
```

[image]